# How to change position of path in svg?

Tags: svg

I have this svg code and I want to use it with 60px width and 60px height. When I change with and height of it, the path that is in it, is be hidden. How can I change position of path?

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1440" height="3575" viewBox="" fill="none">
            <path
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              d="M1237.97 919.405L1235.82 917.741C1235.54 917.527 1234.25 916.554 1232.45 915.637C1232.78 915.358 1233.11 915.055 1233.41 914.723C1236.76 911.066 1237.53 905.172 1237.56 904.922L1237.9 902.224L1235.31 902.292C1235.62 901.657 1235.89 900.975 1236.07 900.248C1237.28 895.416 1235.13 889.809 1235.04 889.573L1234.06 887.057L1231.71 888.387C1231.04 888.766 1225.13 892.239 1223.88 897.234C1223.09 900.396 1224.11 903.525 1225.06 905.519C1224.73 905.782 1224.43 906.066 1224.15 906.374C1222.73 907.924 1221.98 909.817 1221.6 911.551C1220.55 915.276 1218.02 917.974 1214.07 919.574C1211.62 920.567 1209.31 920.844 1208.32 920.919C1208.2 920.912 1208.07 920.908 1207.94 920.908C1207.82 920.908 1207.69 920.912 1207.57 920.918C1205.3 920.741 1196.39 919.52 1194.26 911.27L1194.17 911.292C1193.78 909.634 1193.05 907.855 1191.72 906.384C1191.46 906.102 1191.19 905.841 1190.9 905.597C1191.86 903.608 1192.92 900.438 1192.12 897.234C1190.87 892.239 1184.96 888.766 1184.29 888.387L1181.94 887.057L1180.96 889.573C1180.87 889.809 1178.72 895.416 1179.93 900.248C1180.11 900.975 1180.37 901.657 1180.69 902.292L1178.07 902.223L1178.4 904.919C1178.43 905.168 1179.2 911.057 1182.51 914.713C1182.81 915.052 1183.14 915.36 1183.48 915.644C1181.68 916.559 1180.39 917.527 1180.12 917.741L1177.97 919.405L1179.94 921.279C1180.12 921.452 1184.42 925.504 1189.29 926.275C1188.39 927.826 1187.89 929.123 1187.78 929.424L1186.83 931.97L1189.49 932.527C1189.62 932.556 1191.48 932.936 1193.89 932.936C1195.83 932.936 1198.12 932.69 1200.15 931.819C1200.68 931.589 1201.18 931.316 1201.65 931.01C1202.8 933.328 1205.18 934.926 1207.94 934.926C1210.71 934.926 1213.1 933.314 1214.24 930.98C1214.72 931.297 1215.24 931.582 1215.79 931.819C1217.82 932.69 1220.11 932.936 1222.05 932.936C1224.45 932.936 1226.31 932.556 1226.45 932.527L1229.11 931.97L1228.16 929.424C1228.05 929.123 1227.54 927.826 1226.65 926.275C1231.52 925.504 1235.82 921.452 1236 921.279L1237.97 919.405ZM1188.25 909.519C1189.25 910.626 1189.69 912.249 1189.85 913.644C1188.56 913.333 1187.02 912.734 1185.97 911.579C1184.95 910.452 1184.23 908.841 1183.76 907.386C1185.42 907.756 1187.25 908.413 1188.25 909.519ZM1227.59 909.529C1227.84 909.257 1228.15 909.012 1228.48 908.792L1229.28 908.366C1229.3 908.354 1229.37 908.316 1229.48 908.252C1230.33 907.864 1231.29 907.582 1232.2 907.384C1231.74 908.788 1231.03 910.398 1229.96 911.568C1228.89 912.744 1227.3 913.346 1225.98 913.654C1226.01 913.382 1226.05 913.099 1226.1 912.81C1226.14 912.688 1226.17 912.565 1226.2 912.441L1226.18 912.436C1226.42 911.41 1226.84 910.35 1227.59 909.529ZM1228.41 898.367C1228.78 896.888 1230.15 895.4 1231.49 894.263C1231.77 895.799 1231.91 897.605 1231.54 899.115C1231.15 900.678 1230.01 901.97 1228.99 902.866C1228.45 901.536 1228.04 899.855 1228.41 898.367ZM1184.5 894.263C1185.84 895.4 1187.21 896.889 1187.58 898.367C1187.96 899.855 1187.55 901.536 1187.01 902.866C1185.98 901.968 1184.85 900.675 1184.46 899.115C1184.08 897.605 1184.22 895.799 1184.5 894.263ZM1190.53 918.577C1192.02 918.801 1193.39 919.784 1194.41 920.765C1194.3 920.827 1194.19 920.89 1194.08 920.957C1192.93 921.472 1191.49 921.882 1190.07 921.668C1188.54 921.439 1186.94 920.632 1185.64 919.793C1187.18 919.016 1189.04 918.352 1190.53 918.577ZM1198.31 927.524C1196.89 928.132 1195.1 928.288 1193.55 928.261C1194.3 927.037 1195.27 925.773 1196.38 925.035C1196.71 924.877 1197.02 924.717 1197.31 924.559C1198.65 924.067 1200.25 924.191 1201.56 924.479C1200.84 925.614 1199.76 926.901 1198.31 927.524ZM1207.94 930.254C1206.65 930.254 1205.6 929.206 1205.6 927.917C1205.6 926.733 1206.49 925.755 1207.63 925.603C1207.74 925.61 1207.82 925.613 1207.89 925.615V925.62C1207.9 925.62 1207.93 925.619 1207.97 925.618C1208.01 925.619 1208.04 925.62 1208.05 925.62V925.615C1208.11 925.614 1208.18 925.61 1208.26 925.606C1209.4 925.764 1210.28 926.739 1210.28 927.917C1210.28 929.205 1209.23 930.254 1207.94 930.254ZM1217.63 927.524C1216.18 926.9 1215.09 925.611 1214.38 924.477C1215.64 924.191 1217.23 924.044 1218.63 924.559C1218.92 924.717 1219.23 924.877 1219.56 925.035C1220.67 925.774 1221.65 927.042 1222.39 928.266C1220.84 928.293 1219.06 928.137 1217.63 927.524ZM1225.87 921.668C1224.45 921.882 1223.01 921.472 1221.85 920.957C1221.75 920.891 1221.64 920.827 1221.53 920.765C1222.55 919.783 1223.92 918.801 1225.4 918.577C1226.91 918.35 1228.77 919.012 1230.31 919.794C1229.01 920.631 1227.41 921.437 1225.87 921.668ZM1205.72 911.096V898.844C1204.02 900.013 1201.97 900.7 1199.76 900.7V896.027C1202.98 896.027 1205.6 893.407 1205.6 890.186H1210.28V890.207H1210.39V911.096H1205.72ZM1191.93 887.738L1188.21 884.911C1190.47 881.935 1193.42 879.471 1196.75 877.784C1200.24 876.014 1204 875.117 1207.94 875.117C1211.85 875.117 1215.75 876.054 1219.21 877.828C1222.56 879.541 1225.52 882.044 1227.78 885.062L1224.04 887.861C1220.2 882.732 1214.33 879.79 1207.94 879.79C1201.6 879.79 1195.77 882.687 1191.93 887.738Z"
              fill="#F2994A"
            />
</svg>
```

Comment: Use `<svg width="60" viewBox="1178 875 60 60" ...`

Comment: Thank you. How did you calculate first two items of viewBox?

Comment: I've used the getBBox() method for the path. This is returning the position (x,y) and the size of the bounding box. Suposing that bb is the bounding box `viewBox="bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height"`